# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=productManagement

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had a simple SPA and then after following Andrew Connel course on pluralsight (2nd module), I have some error.  Basically the 2nd module is to create a config exception handler and a global config object.

It seems I am missing something, but cant figure out what exactly.

index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="productManagement">
<head>
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />|
    <link href="../Content/App.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
</head>
<body>

    <div id="pageWidth">
        <div id="chrome_ctrl_container"></div>
        <div id="contentBody">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="navbar-brand"
                       ui-sref="home">Acme Product Management</a>
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button"
                                class="navbar-toggle"
                                data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a ui-sref="productList">Product List</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a ui-sref="productEdit.info({productId:0})">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                                    Add Product
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="container">
                <div ui-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Common Libraries -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/15/core.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/15/SP.UI.Controls.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.2/angular-resource.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.2/angular-mocks.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/lib/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/lib/ui-utils.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.13/d3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/lib/angular-charts.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- my libraries -->
    <script src="../Scripts/lib/jquery-extensions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- App Bootstrapping -->
    <script src="../Scripts/App/App.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/App/config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/App/config.exceptionHandler.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <script src="../Scripts/App/Common/Services/common.services.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/App/Common/Services/productResource.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/App/Common/Services/productResourceMock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/App/Common/Services/productService.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/App/Common/Services/productdataservice.js"></script>

    <!--Controllers -->
    <script src="../Scripts/App/Products/productListCtrl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/App/Products/productDetailCtrl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/App/Products/productEditCtrl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/App/Prices/priceAnalyticsCtrl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- App Chrome-->
    <script src="../Scripts/lib/appchrome.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("productManagement",
                            ["common.services",
                             "ui.router",
                             "ui.mask",
                             "ui.bootstrap",
                             "angularCharts"]);

    app.config(function ($provide) {
        $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler",
            ["$delegate",
                function ($delegate) {
                    return function (exception, cause) {
                        exception.message = "Please contact the Help Desk! \n Message: " +
                                                                exception.message;
                        $delegate(exception, cause);
                        alert(exception.message);
                    };
                }]);
    });

    app.config(["$stateProvider",
                "$urlRouterProvider",
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

            $stateProvider
                .state("home", {
                    url: "/",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/welcomeView.html"
                })
                // Products
                .state("productList", {
                    url: "/products",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/products/productListView.html",
                    controller: "ProductListCtrl as vm"
                })
                .state("productEdit", {
                    abstract: true,
                    url: "/products/edit/:productId",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/products/productEditView.html",
                    controller: "ProductEditCtrl as vm",
                    resolve: {
                        productResource: "productResource",

                        product: function (productResource, $stateParams) {
                            var productId = $stateParams.productId;
                            return productResource.get({ productId: productId }).$promise;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .state("productEdit.info", {
                    url: "/info",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/products/productEditInfoView.html"
                })
                .state("productEdit.price", {
                    url: "/price",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/products/productEditPriceView.html"
                })
                .state("productEdit.tags", {
                    url: "/tags",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/products/productEditTagsView.html"
                })

                .state("productDetail", {
                    url: "/products/:productId",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/products/productDetailView.html",
                    controller: "ProductDetailCtrl as vm",
                    resolve: {
                        productResource: "productResource",

                        product: function (productResource, $stateParams) {
                            var productId = $stateParams.productId;
                            return productResource.get({ productId: productId }).$promise;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .state("priceAnalytics", {
                    url: "/priceAnalytics",
                    templateUrl: "../Scripts/app/prices/priceAnalyticsView.html",
                    controller: "PriceAnalyticsCtrl",
                    resolve: {
                        productResource: "productResource",

                        products: function (productResource) {
                            return productResource.query().$promise;
                        }
                    }
                })

        }]
    );
}());
```

Config.js

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('productManagement');

  var events = {
    controllerActivateSuccess: 'controller.activateSuccess'
  };

  var config = {
    // config the exceptionHandler decorator
    appErrorPrefix: '[SYSERR] ',
    // app events
    events: events,
    // app version
    version: '1.0.0.0',
    // debug notification settings
    showDebugNotiSetting: true
  };

  // create a global variable on app called 'config'
  app.value('config', config);

  // configure the angular logging service before startup
  app.config(['$logProvider', function ($logProvider) {
    // turn debugging off/on (no info or warn)
    if ($logProvider.debugEnabled) {
      $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
    }
  }]);

  // configure the common configuration
  app.config(['commonConfigProvider', function (cfg) {
    cfg.config.controllerActivateSuccessEvent = config.events.controllerActivateSuccess;
  }]);
})();
```

ConfigExceptionHandler.js

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('productManagement');

  app.config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler',
                        ['$delegate', 'config', 'logger', extendExceptionHandler]);
  });

  // Extend $exceptionHandler service to display error notification
  function extendExceptionHandler($delegate, config, logger) {
    var appErrorPrefix = config.appErrorPrefix;

    return function (exception, cause) {
      $delegate(exception, cause);
      if (appErrorPrefix && exception.message.indexOf(appErrorPrefix) === 0) { return; }

      var errorData = {
        exception: exception,
        cause: cause
      };

      var msg = appErrorPrefix + exception.message;

      logger.logError(msg, errorData, true);
    };
  }
})();
```

Comment: You are missing some sort of Angular dependency in your app, something like ngRoute maybe. CLicking on the message in Console in Chrome should give you more details about this.

Comment: try change declaring your module like `var app = angular.module('productManagement',[]);` and `var app = angular.module('productManagement',[]);`

Comment: also, methinks you redeclare your module `productManagement` in __ConfigExceptionHandler.js__